# How to access input element in php withot using get or post method?

Tags: php

How can I access text box element in php file without using form tag.Just as

> getElementById['id']

in JavaScript.

Comment: you need to learn the difference between client-side and server-side programming.

Comment: try this: http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Comment: Weird, when you are using var in php, then use it as many times as you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no other choices than using `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`, this is where your vars will be:

```
$_GET['txtbox'];  //in case of method="get"
$_POST['txtbox'];  //in case of method="post"
$_REQUEST['txtbox']; //in any case
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

GET and POST are the methods used by your web browser to transmit user input to the web server for processing in your PHP script.

That is what you have.

If you're expecting your PHP code to be able to directly access DOM elements at "run-time" just because your PHP code is visible in the same `.php` file as your Javascript and HTML code, then you ought to research the principle that PHP is a *preprocessor*. The web browser sees no PHP code.